# Ubuntu Stuck at BusyBox `[Firmware Bug] : TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)`

Tags: boot, initramfs, busybox

I am having problems booting my Ubuntu after an *attempted* hardware fix today. My laptop was working fine but had some minor issues, so we tried a different motherboard, which had a major issue, so we changed it back to the original board. However, now I have problem booting.

The title pretty much says it all. I am using Ubuntu 16.04, but on boot, I get:

```
[    0:000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
```

and I am now stuck at the BusyBox `(initramfs)`.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I am not so familiar with bash or initramfs, so I would appreciate a detailed step-to-step guide if possible.

Comment: Has this computer ever booted sucessfully using any operating system?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, let me add a bit more context to the post, actually.

Comment: What CPU model do you have? I assume you should file a bug report against `intel-microcode` (if it's an Intel CPU) or `amd-microcode` in case of an AMD CPU. [Here is how.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) Unfortunately I don't know how to help you fix your issue though.

Comment: Btw, is this post on Ubuntuforums also by you? It was posted around the same time. Otherwise there's someone having the same problem as you do: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2369425

Comment: Yup, that's me :/

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact error on a system that booted fine until I upgraded to ubuntu 17.10 at which point it couldn't get past it. I upgraded the bios on my motherboard and now it works perfectly.

This was on my Gigabyte MB: GA-B150N-Phoenix-WIFI-rev-10

http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/GA-B150N-Phoenix-WIFI-rev-10#support-dl

It was running a bios from 2016, I downloaded the latest v22a to a usb, entered the bios setup on the machine and hit f8 to open the flash util.

Hope that helps someone.